# Points on line with Python

Tags: python

If I have a list of values:

```
A = [100,100,100,100]
```

How would I Pythonicly scale these values so that `A[0] = 0` and `A[3] = 100`
If you use this values as points you can draw a straight line from point `0` to point `3`.

Comment: In other words, how to generate an equally-spaced list starting at `x` and going to `y`? Is there any relation to the points that were originally in the list? Have you tried anything?

Comment: How can you use one value as a point. And what is point 0 and point 3. In one dimension... every line is a straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
A = [100,100,100,100]
Scale = 1

B= []
for idx, val in enumerate(A):
    B.append( (val*idx)/(len(A)-1) * Scale)
```

Note that the output will be an integer array, if you want more precision you can use floats instead

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
>>> A = [100,100,100,100]
>>> range(0, A[-1], A[-1]/(len(A)-1))
[0, 33, 66, 99]
```

As this is integer, it will not be exactly 100 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use floats (which seems to be what you'd want to use, given the parameters of the question, as integers cannot give you a smooth line from `A` to `B` in most cases), consider this option:

```
A = [100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0]

startScale = 0.0
endScale = 1.0
scaleDiff = endScale - startScale
lenA = len(A)

scaledA = [A[i] * (scaleDiff * i / (lenA-1) + startScale) for i in xrange(lenA)]
print scaledA
```

**Output**

```
[0.0, 33.333333333333329, 66.666666666666657, 100.0]
```

With this solution, you have the added flexibility of specifying multiplier values for `start` and `end`. This means you can easily get other results like:

```
# Using these scale values...
startScale = 0.25
endScale = 2.0

[25.0, 83.333333333333343, 141.66666666666669, 200.0]
```

Comment: This one of yours is going to help me with my spiral adjustments. Thank you.